# URL Rewrites are not generated after product import

Tags: magento2, magento-2.3

I am trying to import products into my store however the rewrites are not generated in the database at all so the long default url remains. Anyone faced this issue and solved it before without using an external module?
The URL key is correctly set at the product page.

[incorrect url](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VHcwd.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [faonni module indexer](https://packagist.org/packages/faonni/module-indexer-url-rewrite) which will create URL rewrite for your products category and cms pages.
After installing the extension you can run indexer commands as follows.

```
php bin/magento indexer:reindex category_url_rewrite
php bin/magento indexer:reindex product_url_rewrite
php bin/magento indexer:reindex cms_page_url_rewrite
```

Comment: I wanted to solve this without introducing an additional extension.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with the importer. When there are no images available however they are defined in the feed file the importer will stop processing further information. For example it won't create the rewrites in the database and won't process stock related information. Won't create the relevant stock related records in the database neither. Database tables impacted ( the ones I actually found so far ):

url_rewrite
cataloginventory_stock_status
cataloginventory_stock_item

Answer (score 0):

I'm replying to an almost 5 year old question here, but I hope it might help someone in the future (as it's still applicable)

I had the same issue, I couldn't for the life of me figure out why - until I tried to create the rewrite manually in the CMS.

It turns out that when I imported the products, I didn't assign them a store. It told me that the product wasn't assigned to any stores.

1. Go to the product in the CMS
2. Expand `Product in websites`
3. Make sure `Main Website` is checked (or whatever stores your site has). If this product has children, do the same for those too.

Reindex, clear your cache etc